# Getting User info from session id - trying to reverse engineer Passport ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, passport.js

How does Passport for Express find the User object in the database given session information? What about the session id can locate a user in the DB?

I have two servers that need to share authentication, but the authentication is first arrived at by OAuth with Twitter. So server A authenticates and then makes a request to server B - I was thinking of somehow passing the session id to server B and the having server B query the database looking for the user that pertains to that session. Perhaps it's not the secure I just want to know for now how Passport finds a user given session info?

For example, here is a typical session object in the database using the standard Express-Session module:

```
{
  _id: "WnWPfjdn-WHNn2kEDbvCwKBndcJJGe7O",
  session: "{\"cookie\":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"secure":true,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/\"}}",
  expires: ISODate("2015-11-08T06:38:16.421Z")
}
```

how can I take the _id of this session and turn it into a User?

Comment: Checkout https://www.airpair.com/express/posts/expressjs-and-passportjs-sessions-deep-dive